How to stop footer change vertical height of details section in crystal report?
I've designed a bill in crystal report.
Before coming to main issue, I discuss about my work.
Following is the image of my work for bill.

Everything in here works fine for now.
And here are some extra details before proceeding to main issue.

This image below describes page footer being supressed as I only want it to get printed on last page. else there should be bill continued on next page option which is written in pagefooter C 



3rd Image below just to show the margin.

The bottom margin is set higher because I sometimes want to print in A4 pages and sometimes A5, so I set margin programmatically accordingly and this works fine for me. The desired result by doing this is details section with expand and shrink which is needed. 

NOW THE MAIN ISSUE.
I Want to add a new page footer, but it shrinks the details section which is expected but I don't want to shrink details section if the pagefooter is supressed. Currently details section gives me about 8 rows but after I add a new pagefooter it shrinks to 4 or 2 or error depending on height of pagefooter. Even I supress the new pagefooter, the details section compromises its height.
So my main question is How to stop footer change vertical height of details section in crystal report?
